# Resolving conversion warnings with compound assignment operators

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion

At our company we have a policy to compile with `-Wconversion` which produces some conversion warnings. While I do agree this extra checking prevents bugs, it is annoying to see warnings on shorthand operators such as in the following case:

```
uint8_t byte;
byte += 8; // conversion to 'uint8_t' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

Now this can be solved by rewriting it as `byte = (uint8_t)(byte+8)` which in turn reduces code readability.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: How exactly do you compile this? Compiling both with gcc or g++ on OSX doesn't give any warnings :(

Comment: Compile with gcc and `-Wconversion` and it should report a warning.

Comment: Well, I think this is Clang playing some bad joke on me. Here's what I do:
`gcc -Wconversion -std=c99 -o prog main.c` doesn't give me any warnings. Compiling with `-Wall` just suggests to initialize the variable. Gonna try it on Linux in a sec.

Comment: Now that's weird. Let's see what other people has to say about it.

Comment: I think in this case the cure (cast) is worse than the cause. Even [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion) says *"Wconversion is designed for a niche of uses"*. So it's probably not worth it to keep `Wconversion` enabled all the time.

Comment: `-Wconversion` does not even get enabled by `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, precisely because it has virtually no value as a warning (outside of niche cases). I agree with user694733 that any cure for this warning only makes code a lot worse - whether it be casting, explicit conversion, or bracketing code with `#pragma gcc diagnostic` (push/ignored/pop).

Comment: Mandatory implicit promotion breaks the type system and defeats all attempts at silencing the warning by making all operands be of the right type, like `byte += uint8_t(8)`. It's the same kind of unfortunate mechanism as what makes 0 an `int` that cannot be assigned to a `uint8_t` and that causes warnings about signed/unsigned mismatch (also with things `x ? 0 : 1`) unless you 'u' all your literals. 0 through 127 should be implicitly compatible (i.e. not provoke any superfluous warnings) with any integral type that has at least 8 bits, regardless of whether it is signed or unsigned.

Comment: Well, we are inside of that niche case :-)  [GCC wiki entry](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion) explains where conversion warnings are useful and, developing embedded stuff, this saved us a few times already. I guess I'll have to stick to the ugly cure.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the warnings on Linux. Looking through "C: A Reference Manual", it seems that there is no other better way. As DarthGizka mentioned, due to implicit arithmetic conversions, both operands of `+=` or `+` operator are promoted to `int`, even if they are both of `uint8_t` type (which is usually a typedef to `unsigned char`).

Comment: If flag is needed, I think that it might be safer to use pragma to disable warning temporarily, than use the cast. Casting might hide other bugs or create unintended side effects (for example if variable is later refactored to `uint16_t`, but cast change is forgotten)

Comment: In C++, you never need a C-style cast and you shouldn't use it, because it prevents pretty much **all** type checking. For converting built-in types, prefer to use the conversion constructor syntax: `uint8_t(8)`.

Comment: note: There is a duplicate, I'm just too lazy to search for it...

Comment: @DDrmmr In C++ the "conversion constructor syntax" (also called "functional cast expression") is identical to a C-style cast. Both these should be avoided in equal measures.
see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast "2) The functional cast expression ....  is exactly equivalent to the corresponding C-style cast expression."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the reason why you get the warning, namely that the integer constant `8` is of type `int`. That everything in C has to be promoted to (signed) `int` is a well-known design flaw of the language.

Suppose you had `byte += 256;` or `byte += -1;` or `byte += function_that_returns_int();`. All of them are potentially severe bugs, so the warning certainly makes sense to enable.

There's really no other work-around than to cast the result of the operation to the intended type, `uint8_t`. Which isn't necessarily a bad thing, as it creates self-documenting code saying "yes, I have actually considered which types that are used in this calculation so there should be no overflows".

Comment: Consider `uint8_t b1 = 0, b2 = 1; b1 |= b2;`  This will still give a warning because `b1 + b2` is type int.  The only option I've found is to either not use `-Wconversion` or to never use compound operators on anything smaller than an int.

Unfortunately, I have found that `-Wconversion` is helpful in making bugs more apparent as well as helping to keep APIs consistent.

Comment: @RyanB It's not really the fault of the compiler, but the language. Operations on small integer types _are_ dangerous. Just make a subtle change to your example: `b1 |= b2 - 2;` and suddenly we have signed and with negative operands everywhere. Which is one reason why C programming for small 8/16 bit microcontrollers actually requires more detailed language knowledge than when programming large programs for high-end ARM or PC.

Answer (score -1):

This may not exactly solve your problem but at least gives you a hint that there is a solution for almost everything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SAFE_ADD(a,b) ((a) = (typeof(a))((a)+(b)))

int main(void)
{
        uint8_t byte = 0;
        SAFE_ADD(byte, 8);

        fprintf(stderr, "byte = %d \n", byte);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiled w/o warnings with gcc 4.8.4 (gcc -Wall -Wconversion byte.c)
Hope that helps.

Comment: Now compile with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wconversion byte.c`. `typeof` is obsolete non-standard crap. Use C11 `_Generic` instead.

Comment: You missed the point, it doesn't matter, look at old comments above, instead of finding a reasonable solution they say "tell your company they should change their policy..., why do you use -Wconversion that is not even a warning, this.. and that.." What I do is I presented an example (more like template) solution. What you say is can be easily fixed with writing actual type (uint8_t against typeof) and rename macro as SAFE_ADD_UINT8 or anything you like, and I know typeof is also a GCC extension, I don't use it personally."